# postgresql 10 date range contraint

Tags: postgresql, range, constraints, postgresql-10

I want to make a date range constraint in postgresql 10. In postgresql 9.6 this worked:

```
CREATE TABLE project_lines (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  project_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES projects(id),
  description VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  start_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  end_time TIMESTAMP CHECK(end_time > start_time),
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  CONSTRAINT overlapping_times EXCLUDE USING GIST(
    project_id WITH =,
    tstzrange(start_time, COALESCE(end_time, 'infinity')) WITH &&
  )
);
```

But in postgresql 10 I am getting this error:
`functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`

How can I make this constraint working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `start_time` and `end_time` columns have type `TIMESTAMP`, while the `tstzrange` expects `TIMESTAMPTZ` (with time zone). Apparently this conversion happens automatically, but it's not considered "IMMUTABLE".

The documentation at
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/xfunc-volatility.html says

> A common 
>   error is to label a function IMMUTABLE when its results depend on a configuration parameter. For example, a function that manipulates timestamps might well have results that depend on the TimeZone setting. For safety, such functions should be labeled STABLE instead.

You should probably use `tsrange` instead, or explicitly convert to timestamp with time zone (in a way that doesn't depend on server settings):

```
tstzrange(start_time at time zone 'utc', COALESCE(end_time at time zone 'utc', 'infinity')) WITH &&
```

I don't know what has changed between versions, though (and I get the same error message with 9.6.6).